# objective-c concatenate NSString

Tags: iphone, nsstring, concatenation

I have problems to concatenate NSString.

Each time I pushed a button I want that something ("aux") is added to my string ("myString"). so:

```
NSString *aux = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", buttonIndex];

myString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",posTargetaText,aux];

aux = nil;
```

The first time i pushed the button it works good but the second it doesn't work.

Some help please?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it doesn't work"? What are you expecting to see? What do you actually see? Can you post some sample output?

Comment: What happens second time, does it crash or what output are you getting?????

Comment: Check the value of   `posTargetaText` ..

Comment: Thanks every body

The problem was that I not initzialize the NSString correctly.

I used:

myString = @"";

the correct way is:

myString = [NSString string];

Answer (score 13):

So you can certainly use `stringWithFormat`, but why don't you use `stringByAppendingString` instead, since that's exactly what you want to do?

```
NSString *newString = [firstString stringByAppendingString:secondString];
```

You really don't need to use a mutable string unless you have a compelling reason to.

Comment: He has a "/" between the two strings. stringWithFormat seems easiest.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure what exactly you want to do. But as per your code aux will have new buttonIndex value each time and You will have always new mystring when ever you tap button.

If you want to append string always in myString that you need to do like this.

```
myString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/%@",myString,posTargetaText,aux];
```

You suppose to add previous value of myString as well in new myString string ?

Not sure this is what you want or something different. Please explain in detail if this is not.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna concatenate two strings use NSMutablestring and method appendstring instead of NSString.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use NSMutableString.

Comment: How does this differ from other answers?